Sci-fi novel with a side character who created children within virtual reality and whose human life/body wasted away
I’ve been trying to remember what book this is from for years and I have not been able to figure it out. This isn’t the main character of the book but more of a cautionary tale/side character, perhaps the protagonist’s aunt (but not sure). She has created a virtual reality world for herself in which she has realistic (but AI) children (maybe her children had died, or she wasn’t able to have kids? Something related to escaping from a traumatic reality). Consequently, she does not engage in the human/3-D world much at all and wastes away.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about approximately when you read it?  Do you remember the cover art?  Was it set on Earth?  In a specific country/locality?

I read it about 10 years ago, but I think it was an older book. I think it was a post collapse version of earth but I’m not 100% it may have been an earth-like planet. The characters were human. The world building is really lovely from what I remember and one of the themes explored was the dangers of over engagement in virtual worlds, and the character who broke with the guidelines and created virtual children suffered greatly for their mistake
